# Date time issue, returning one day less

Tags: java

The below code is returning one day less than what i passed, why is it returning one day less "Fri Aug 27 13:00:00 PDT 2010".

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

   Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", locale);
   TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-4");

   dateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);

   System.out.println(dateFormat.parse("2010-08-28"));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122608/simpledateformat-parse-loses-timezone

Comment: This thread had the same problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581112/java-simpledateformat-timezone-parsing

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the strange output is your system time zone.

For example, on my system I'm working with `UTC+2` and your code prints

```
Fri Aug 27 23:00:00 BST 2010
```

If I change the system time zone to `UTC` I get

```
Fri Aug 27 21:00:00 BST 2010
```

which makes two hour difference in the output.

So, what appears to be happening is that the date `00:00, 28 Aug 2010` in `UTC-4` is calculated to the time zone that's specified in your system settings and then printed in the terminal.

Comment: thank you for answer, but what is the use setting timezone when parsing TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-4");

   dateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);

Comment: And it prints 21:00 instead of 20:00 because of the summertime on 27 Aug 2010

Answer (score 1):

The output will depend on your system's timezone. What you're parsing is essentially 2010-08-28 00:00:00 on timezone GMT-4. And when you print it it shows this time on your system's timezone.

Answer (score 0):

See the time at `Fri Aug 27 13:00:00 PDT 2010`? It's 13:00 PDT, so I'd suggest that you print using a dedicated `SimpleDateFormat` with the target time zone...